# how to interpret this phrase/sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

the phrase/sentence is:

"We go behind the scenes after a momentum Supreme Court term."

the word "momentum" used in this is the puzzle to me.
what did  the author of it means by that? is it about the impetus a new Supreme Court term can give?

Comment: I think it's a typo. It should be "momentous".  Momentous means very significant/important.

Comment: @Billy Kerr not a typos it was like a pun by changing "Momentous" for "momentum" but the resulting phrase I don't know what that means

Comment: I don't think so. It just doesn't work. Momentum is a noun.  A "momentum term" doesn't make any make sense, IMHO, which is why I suspect it's a typo or just a mistake.  Also this isn't how puns work in English.  Puns are usually clever/funny, but this is neither.

Comment: @Billy Kerr, you have fair points. But according to explanatory of the author he flexed "Momentum" to be an adjective and the intention of pun was not to be funny but to make a critic. get it so he disregarded the grammar LOL. agree?

Comment: What's the source? If it's the New York Times website, that's [not what it says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdAYm.jpg).

Comment: Which author? What explanation? Do you have the source?

Comment: @Laurel, did you get that image off www.nytimes.com itself? And can you say exactly what your search terms were and on what search engine? I can get hits only if I omit "momentum", or replace it with "momentous", and of Google, DuckDuckGo, and Bing, only Google found it. Neither DuckDuckGo nor Bing returned a single result, and even the one from Google was a fairly obscure-looking Wordpress site. It's probably nothing, but something about the whole shebang is triggering my inner phishing early warning.

Comment: @tkp I got it off of the WordPress site (it mirrors an older version of the NYT website to anyone with a Google user agent, but shows spam to everyone else — classic spammer stuff). I got the image via Google's cache — I would not recommend visiting the site directly as nothing good will come of it.

Comment: @all the intention of the author was: saying that a Supreme Court term would give new impetus or new animus tom someone. that by replacing the "Momentous" for "momentum" and the setence source is the exact Lauel said. get it? i thought it was clever. just wanted to know if any one else would get this author's idea

Comment: Thanks Laurel. Yeah, I followed the search result in an isolated sandbox and it bounces around a bunch of spam-ish URLs before settling on one of them. So a question then for the OP, @Lynerapintcho: exactly where did you get the information that the author used "momentum" instead of "momentous", for purposes of a pun?

Comment: @tkp, fair question though, it came from a WhatsApp group. I friend of mine living in California is a daily reader of NYT and made this pun with this sentence, and I just wanted to test if someone else would get his intention OR even if that makes sense in some level or make any sense for a joke

Comment: Ok. But then I agree with Billy. Your friend's intention is simply not being served by using "momentum" instead of the original (and correct) "momentous". All it's doing is confusing a bunch of native speakers, and even making one of them think the whole thing might be a cyber attack! 

Comment: @tkp, kkkkkkkkkkk. get it thanks. one more question though. how would that be somehow related to a cyber attack?

Comment: @tkp, also I think the reason people in WhatsApp group got the joke was the conversation context, right?

Comment: @Lynerapintcho, if they really did get the joke then I'm at a loss as to why. I certainly didn't get it, but maybe that's just me! I've attempted an answer below, to try to explain my sad, humorless existence. 

Answer (score 1):

OK, now that you've explained the background, I think there is an interesting question here. The core of it seems to be asking if the attempt at wordplay succeeded or failed, and why.

So, for ease of reading, we're looking at the effect of changing from:

> We go behind the scenes after a **momentous** Supreme Court term.

to:

> We go behind the scenes after a **momentum** Supreme Court term.

I think it does fail, and I can think of at least three reasons.

1. The confusing grammar error with no compensating benefit
2. The extent of difference in meaning between "momentous" and "momentum" despite their similar etymologies.
3. The ineffective *directionality* of change.

In turn then.

1. The change from adjective to noun produces a grammatically broken sentence.  Now given that the text is a headline, that isn't *necessarily* fatal; headlines and poetry can sometimes get away with, or even make use of grammatical errors in order to create some desirable "higher" linguistic effect. But in this case, no such higher effect is created.
2. Although "momentum" and "momentous" probably have similar etymologies, their contemporary meanings are too far apart to allow the intended pun to do much. In modern English, "momentous" conveys *importance* or *gravity* whereas "momentum" connotes continuity and a thing's capacity to induce change in something else. Finally:
3. Even if the meanings of the words had been such that the pun could have worked, the "direction" is from a word of greater emotive force, to one of less emotive force. That is ineffective. You can see that if we reverse things. Suppose the original had been the following (fixing the grammar error):

> We go behind the scenes after a **momentum-inducing** Supreme Court term.

And then your friend had rewritten it as:

> We go behind the scenes after a **momentous** Supreme Court term.

Now that perhaps *could* be seen as a nice piece of wordplay; the sort of thing to draw a smile, and appreciative comments of, *"Ah, I see what you did there!"* The reason is that it implies that the fairly mundane character of the Supreme Court term (it merely induced some momentum) was actually far from mundane (it was grave and significant).

Unfortunately, as it stands, your friend's change moves in the opposite direction, from the profound to the mundane. Were it not for the first two problems, then I guess *maybe* it could have had some use. But I doubt it.

Perhaps the bottom line here is that if the pun had worked, it..well, it would have worked! It wouldn't have taken umpteen comments and answers analyzing it to extract the cleverness. Like a joke, if it needs explained it didn't work.

Comment: thanks for the attention and to work up an answer so that I could see the possible point of confusion. according to google translator in my country (brazil), it gives those options as momentum's translations: "impetus, momentum, rush, impulse, impetuosity, dash" so imagine aSupreme Court term. that wpuld give some new mind to someone's  way of seeing life. That could be then said a "momentum Supreme Court term" to that person assuming "momentum " to mean impetus, get it?

Comment: Yeah, I get it *now* -- i.e. now that you've explained it. But even now I'm of the view that while your friend's intentions are (now) clear, they are not served by his or her choice of words. He or she may *want* to convey impetus, but that's not what the chosen words do.

Comment: isn't the option "impetus" as definition of "momentum" popular in USA?

Comment: I don't think so. *Momentum* is a measure of an object's mass and velocity. In physics, it is literally: *p = mv*. So *momentum* is something an object **has**. By contrast, *impetus* seems closer in meaning to another physics term, *impulse* which is equivalent to the *change* in an object's *momentum*. Often taught as *force* multiplied by *time*, *impulse* is something an object **experiences**. So I, for my part, would not use "impetus" as the definition for "momentum". And while my English is predominately that of the UK, I reckon this applies to the USA as well.